# How can I write the Apache configuration two different sites?

Tags: apache

How can I write the Apache configuration to make two different sites on the same domain through a slash

Example:

site.ru - 1 site,

site.ru/app - 2 site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache configuration, you should specify full URL without the part which goes after the slash, i.e.:

```
ServerName "site.ru:80"
```

It is not possible to define `site.ru/app` as a separate virtual host.
However, you can simply move the content of the second website to a subdirectory of the first one. For example, if:

```
ServerName "site.ru:80"
DocumentRoot "/var/www/httpdocs"
```

Then `/var/www/httpdocs/app` will be the directory with the content of the second website.

Another option is to create two virtual hosts, and then to add a rewrite rule to the first domain configuration.
Let's take two domains: `site.ru` and `siteapp.ru`. Requests to `site.ru/app` can be redirected to `siteapp.ru` using the following on `site.ru`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/app/(.*)$ http://siteapp.ru/$1
```